# Is it a wrong icon assigned to "firefox" tag?

Tags: support, sponsored-tags

I think the Firefox tag in StackOverflow have a wrong icon:

[image]

We all know that the icon of firefox shall be

[image]

So what's wrong with this tag?

Comment: [Who stole the fox?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204433/who-stole-the-fox)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not a bug; it's the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) logo.

For completeness (h/t animuson's comment): [Who stole the fox?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204433/who-stole-the-fox)

Comment: As the person who received that logo from Mozilla themselves (and uploaded it), I can say that @ed cottrell is 100% correct.

Comment: @stevvve, I do not agree. The tag says "Firefox" not "MDN" and hence, the logo/icon is incorrect and confusing.

Comment: I get you what you're saying, @tborychowski, but as the copyright holder it is up to Mozilla to decide which icon to use. That said, if they wanted to use an image of a hamburger or a shoe, we'd cry foul. Because the MDN logo is relevant, though perhaps not as obvious as the Mozilla logo, we're cool with it for now. Alllll that aside, I'll bring this up with our contacts the next time we speak with Mozilla.

Comment: @stevvve, that's fantastic! Thank you :-)

Comment: I still agree with @tborychowski's original comment.  Just because the icon isn't blatantly "wrong" doesn't mean it's right.